Vulkan Application only render Correctly After the 3rd program execution
I'm encountering a strange issue with my vulkan renderer.
The program behaves differently depending on how many times it has been excuted,
First Run & Second Run : The first 1-2 frame do not render. and next frame, occur validation error like below.
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkAcquireNextImageKHR-semaphore-01779 ] Object 0: handle = 0xb9181f0000000029, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SEMAPHORE; | MessageID = 0x5717e75b | vkAcquireNextImageKHR():  Semaphore must not have any pending operations. The Vulkan spec states: If semaphore is not VK_NULL_HANDLE it must not have any uncompleted signal or wait operations pending (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkAcquireNextImageKHR-semaphore-01779) 
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetFences-pFences-01123 ] Object 0: handle = 0x2e2cd000000002b, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_FENCE; | MessageID = 0x68a5074e | vkResetFences(): pFences[0] (VkFence 0x2e2cd000000002b[]) is in use. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pFences must not be currently associated with any queue command that has not yet completed execution on that queue (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetFences-pFences-01123)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045 ] Object 0: handle = 0x270e3b73f90, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; Object 1: handle = 0x2e2941000000001f, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL; | MessageID = 0x1e7883ea | vkResetCommandBuffer():  (VkCommandBuffer 0x270e3b73f90[]) is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkBeginCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00049 ] Object 0: handle = 0x270e3b73f90, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x84029a9f | vkBeginCommandBuffer():  on active VkCommandBuffer 0x270e3b73f90[] before it has completed. You must check command buffer fence before this call. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the recording or pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkBeginCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00049)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00071 ] | MessageID = 0x2e2f4d65 | vkQueueSubmit(): pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[0] VkCommandBuffer 0x270e3b73f90[] is already in use and is not marked for simultaneous use. The Vulkan spec states: If any element of the pCommandBuffers member of any element of pSubmits was not recorded with the VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT, it must not be in the pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00071)
After Third Run : The first frame is still not rendered correctly, but the rest works fine. and not occur validation error.
I'm unsure why this inconsistency occurs.
I'm using Descriptor indexing for drawing multiple model.
The error occur after using Descritor indexing.
My code is here
Render Code :
void Renderer::Render() {

    vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);

    uint32_t imageIdx;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIdx);
    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        RecreateSwapChain();
        std::cout << "Out of Time!\n";
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }
    vkResetFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]); //Delay resetting the fence until after we know for sure we will be submitting work with it.

    vkResetCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[currentFrame], 0);
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = Initializer::InitCommandBufferBeginInfo();
    //beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;
    VkResult res = vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[currentFrame], &beginInfo);
    if (res != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed  to begin recording command buffer!");
    }

    renderFunc(commandBuffers[currentFrame],swapChainFramebuffers[imageIdx],currentFrame);
    
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[currentFrame]);
    if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
    }

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStage[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = Initializer::InitSubmitInfo(1, waitSemaphores,waitStage,1, &commandBuffers[currentFrame], 1, signalSemaphores);
    if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }
    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = Initializer::InitPresentInfo(1, signalSemaphores, 1, &swapChain, &imageIdx);
    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);
    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || framebufferResized) {
        framebufferResized = false;
        RecreateSwapChain();
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }
    vkQueueWaitIdle(presentQueue);
    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}

void drawFunc(VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer, VkFramebuffer framebuffer, uint32_t currentFrame) {
    Renderer* renderer = Renderer::GetInstance();
    if (renderer == nullptr) return;

    VkExtent2D swapChainExtent = renderer->GetSwapChainExtent();
    std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
    clearValues[0].color = { {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f} };
    clearValues[1].depthStencil = {1.0f, 0};
    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = 
        Initializer::InitRenderPassBeginInfo(renderer->GetRenderPass(), framebuffer, { 0,0 }, swapChainExtent, static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size()), clearValues.data());
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffer, &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->GetPipeline());
    
    VkViewport viewport = Initializer::InitViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, static_cast<float>(swapChainExtent.width), static_cast<float>(swapChainExtent.height), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
    
    VkRect2D scissor = Initializer::InitScissor({ 0,0 }, swapChainExtent);
    vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);
    
    //update vertex ubo
    VkExtent2D swapchainExtent = renderer->GetSwapChainExtent();
    vert_ubo.proj = mainCamera.GetProjMat(swapChainExtent.width, swapchainExtent.height);
    vert_ubo.proj[1][1] *= -1;
    vert_ubo.view = mainCamera.GetViewMat();
    renderer->UpdateVertexUniformBuffer(currentFrame, vert_ubo);

    //update frament ubo
    frag_ubo.cameraPos = mainCamera.position;
    renderer->UpdateFragUniformBuffer(currentFrame, frag_ubo);

    //Write here
    
    //bind texture
    VkDescriptorSet descriptorSet = renderer->GetDescriptorSet(currentFrame);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->GetPipelineLayout(), 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->GetPipelineLayout(), 1, 1, &renderer->texDescriptorSets[0], 0, nullptr);

    model.Draw(commandBuffer, renderer->texDescriptorSets[0], renderer->GetDefaultSampler());
}

Model Draw :
void Model::Draw(VkCommandBuffer commadbuffer, VkDescriptorSet texDescriptorSet, VkSampler sampler) {
    Renderer* renderer = Renderer::GetInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < texture_loaded.size(); i++) {
        VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorImageInfo(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, texture_loaded[i].textureImageView, sampler);
        VkWriteDescriptorSet write = Initializer::InitWriteDescriptorSet(texDescriptorSet, 0, i, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, 1, nullptr, &imageInfo);
        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(renderer->device,1, &write, 0,nullptr);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++) {
        meshes[i].Draw(renderer->GetPipelineLayout(),commadbuffer);
    }
}

void Mesh::Draw(VkPipelineLayout pipelineLayout, VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer) {
    GlobalStructs::TextureIndexPushConstant push_constant{};
    if (material.diffTexIdx >= 0) {
        push_constant.diffTexIdx = material.diffTexIdx;
    }
    vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT, 0, sizeof(GlobalStructs::TextureIndexPushConstant), &push_constant);

    VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
    vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &vertexBuffer, offsets);
    vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
    std::cout << indices.size() << std::endl;
    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer,static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()),1,0,0,0);
}

Descriptor Indexing Code :
void DescriptorBuilder::CreateBindlessDescriptorSets(VkDevice device,VkDescriptorSetLayout& outLayout, VkDescriptorPool& outPool, std::vector<VkDescriptorSet>& outSets, uint32_t descriptorCount) {
        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding set_binding = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, descriptorCount, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);
        VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo createInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo(1,&set_binding);
        createInfo.flags = VK_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_UPDATE_AFTER_BIND_POOL_BIT_EXT;

        const VkDescriptorBindingFlagsEXT flags =
            VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_VARIABLE_DESCRIPTOR_COUNT_BIT_EXT |
            VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_PARTIALLY_BOUND_BIT_EXT |
            VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_UPDATE_AFTER_BIND_BIT_EXT |
            VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_UPDATE_UNUSED_WHILE_PENDING_BIT_EXT;
        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBindingFlagsCreateInfoEXT binding_flags{};
        binding_flags.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_BINDING_FLAGS_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
        binding_flags.bindingCount = 1;
        binding_flags.pBindingFlags = &flags;

        createInfo.pNext = &binding_flags;
        if (vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &createInfo, nullptr, &outLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor set layout");
        };
        VkDescriptorPoolSize poolSize;
        poolSize.type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        poolSize.descriptorCount = descriptorCount;
        VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo poolCreateInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorPoolCreateInfo(1, &poolSize, 1);
        poolCreateInfo.flags = VK_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_UPDATE_AFTER_BIND_BIT_EXT;
        if (vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &poolCreateInfo, nullptr, &outPool) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor pool!");
        }
        std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> layouts(1, outLayout);
        VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetAllocateInfo(outPool, static_cast<uint32_t>(layouts.size()), layouts.data());
        VkDescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfoEXT variable_info{};
        variable_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_VARIABLE_DESCRIPTOR_COUNT_ALLOCATE_INFO_EXT;
        variable_info.descriptorSetCount = 1;
        variable_info.pDescriptorCounts = &descriptorCount;
        allocInfo.pNext = &variable_info;
        outSets.resize(1);
        if (vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, outSets.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate descriptor sets!");
        }
    }

Descriptor Code :
// MAX_FRAME_COUNT == 2

void Renderer::CreateDefaultDescriptorSetLayout() {
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding vert_uboLayoutBinding = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT);
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding frag_uboLayoutBinding = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(1, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding samplerLayoutBinding;
    std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding> bindings = { vert_uboLayoutBinding, frag_uboLayoutBinding };
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_TEXTURE_BINDING; i++) {
        samplerLayoutBinding = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutBinding(bindings.size(), VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, 1, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);
        bindings.push_back(samplerLayoutBinding);
    }
    //re-write after create sampler
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo layoutInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo(static_cast<uint32_t>(bindings.size()), bindings.data());
    if (vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &layoutInfo, nullptr, &defaultDescriptorSetLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor set layout");
    }
}

//custom yourself. if you add Descriptorset
void Renderer::CreateDescriptorPool() {
    std::vector<VkDescriptorPoolSize> poolSizes(3);
    poolSizes[0].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    poolSizes[0].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
    poolSizes[1].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    poolSizes[1].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
    poolSizes[2].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
    poolSizes[2].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT) * GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE;
    
    VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo poolInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorPoolCreateInfo(static_cast<uint32_t>(poolSizes.size()),poolSizes.data(), static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT)); 
    if (vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &poolInfo, nullptr, &descriptorPool) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create descriptor pool!");
    }
}

//custom yourself. if you add Descriptorset
void Renderer::CreateDescriptorSets() {
    std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> layouts(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT, defaultDescriptorSetLayout);
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorSetAllocateInfo(descriptorPool,static_cast<uint32_t>(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT),layouts.data());
    descriptorSets.resize(MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
    if (vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, descriptorSets.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate descriptor sets!");
    }
    std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> descriptorWrites;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT; i++) {
        VkDescriptorBufferInfo vertBufferInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorBufferInfo(vertexUniformBuffers[i], sizeof(GlobalStructs::VertexShaderUBO));
        descriptorWrites.push_back(Initializer::InitWriteDescriptorSet(descriptorSets[i], 0, 0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, &vertBufferInfo));
        VkDescriptorBufferInfo fragBufferInfo = Initializer::InitDescriptorBufferInfo(fragUniformBuffers[i], sizeof(GlobalStructs::FragmentShaderUBO));
        descriptorWrites.push_back(Initializer::InitWriteDescriptorSet(descriptorSets[i], 1, 0, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, &fragBufferInfo));
    }
    vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorWrites.size()), descriptorWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);
}

How can I fix this error..
